# extra fields in facebook batch api

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I need all the past events of friends for last year, since parameter is working fine, and it is responding me the results with minimal fields,

{

**name**: "Who's up for an amazing spectacular party in Dubai?",

**start_time**: "2012-12-07T18:00:00+0400",

**end_time**: "2012-12-08T06:00:00+0400",

**timezone**: "Asia/Dubai",

**location**: "Dubai, United Arab Emirates",

**id**: "420084958028590",

**rsvp_status**: "attending"

},

I need to add other fields to,

- owner
- plance
- attendings
- description

Tried like this,

```
 array('method' => 'GET',
      'relative_url' => $user_id.'/statuses/?since='.strtotime('2010-01-01'),

       # 'relative_url' => $user_id.'/events/',

       #'fields' => 'name,end_time,owner'

         ),

);
```

--

```
 array('method' => 'GET',

  'relative_url' => $user_id.'/statuses/?fields=name,end_time,owner&since='.strtotime('2010-01-01'),
         ),

);
```

Comment: So???Add other fields..Go on..

Comment: it i add fields it give error only JSOn data allowed.

Comment: @sankalp if it was simple to add and go, what should i need to pull question here

Comment: code added in post, edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after some hit and trial,

it worked with **url encoding** the **relative_url** parameter,

```
array('method' => 'GET',

  'relative_url' =>  urlencode($userId.'/events/?fields=name,end_time,owner&since='.strtotime('2010-01-01')),
         ),

);
```